# UITabBar item title

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I set the tab bar item title to two lines. Current using the tab bar item to set the image and title.

I just want to create the UI tab bar item with multi line text with center aligned. And also want to move the tab bar image to the top In order to show the multi line title. [image: sample image with one line tab bar item title]

Want to do it in objective c

Comment: You can use UIStackView for resolving this issue and set your label length 2 or 0.
[stackView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYUi.png)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @MubashirMushir ok will try that

Comment: @koen I tried creating UITab bar item but it shows only one line title

Comment: Basically, what you are describing would not be a tab bar. You can write your own view, but do you really want to? You would also have to write your own tab bar controller-like thing, and that gets into some pretty deep weeds.

Comment: @AvinasUdayakumar please show some code as a [example]. See also [ask].